# c++ atioglxx.pdb contains the debug information required to find the source for the module atioglxx.dll

Tags: c++

I keep getting

> atioglxx.pdb not loaded error

and the exception thrown is

> Unhandled exception at 0x61DA5D3A (atioglxx.dll) in opengl_fps.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000. occurred

This started happening after I added some code for loading some shaders and drawing a triangle

I've allready tried updating my amd drivers,cleaning the solution and rebuilding,restarting visual studio,restarting my pc,and googling it

code for loading a the shaders

```
GLuint vsid = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);\\exception thrown here
glShaderSource(vsid, 1, &vs, NULL);
glCompileShader(vsid);

GLint* success = 0;
GLchar infolog[512];

glGetShaderiv(vsid, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, success);
if (!success)
{
    glGetShaderInfoLog(vsid, 512, NULL, infolog);
    std::cout << "shader vs cant compile\n" << infolog << std::endl;
}
GLuint fsid = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
glShaderSource(fsid, 1, &fs, NULL);
glCompileShader(fsid);

glGetShaderiv(fsid, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, success);

if (!success)
{
    glGetShaderInfoLog(vsid, 512, NULL, infolog);
    std::cout << "shader fs cant compile\n" << infolog << std::endl;
}
GLuint shaderprogram = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(shaderprogram, vsid);
glAttachShader(shaderprogram, fsid);
glLinkProgram(shaderprogram);

glGetProgramiv(shaderprogram, GL_LINK_STATUS, success);

if (!success)
{
    glGetShaderInfoLog(shaderprogram, 512, NULL, infolog);
    std::cout << "shader program" << infolog;
}
glDeleteShader(vsid);
glDeleteShader(fsid);
GLfloat vertices[] = {
    -0.5f,-0.5f,0.0f,
    0.5f,-0.5f,0.0f,
    0.0f,0.5f,0.0f
};

GLuint vbo, vao;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GL_FLOAT), (GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

code for rendering

```
win.update();
glUseProgram(shaderprogram);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
glBindVertexArray(0);
win.swapbuffers();
```

Comment: You're looking at the wrong error.  The real error here is the access violation caused by the DLL attempting to write to a NULL address.  Forget about the other message -- it's only telling you that you don't have the debug symbols to examine where in that DLL the crash occurred.  If you look back up the call stack to the top-most symbol in _your_ program that led to the exception, then you'll be able to work backwards from there.

Answer (score 2):

The 3 parameter of `glGetShaderiv` is expecting the address of a `GLint` you are passing the null pointer in as the address to use.

Change:

```
GLint* success = 0;
GLchar infolog[512];

glGetShaderiv(vsid, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, success);
```

To:

```
GLint success = 0;
GLchar infolog[512];

glGetShaderiv(vsid, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
```

And also in other similar places.

Comment: thanks i didn't think assigning success as a pointer would make a difference

Comment: It's an output parameter, and needs a location to store the result.